# Why is data-role="fieldcontain" on this page not styled?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile Docs says if we wrap form element in div containing `data-role="fieldcontain"` proper styles would be applied, like horizontal line at a bottom.

I spent hours trying to figure out why is this not working so I'm just wondering is this feature removed from 1.0 Final or is this bug? I could swear this was working just a few days ago.

As an example I prepared this simple html page with default scripts delivered through CDN: http://jsfiddle.net/eQe5A/.

Can someone please shed some light on this issue.

Thanks,
Klikerko

**EDIT:**

After doing more research I have found that Safari and Opera are only desktop browser that would render jQuery Mobile pages as mobile browser would. My question above is related to special style applied to form elements when browser size is less than 450px. Those styles would add horizontal line divider below form element and would move label above the field if width is less than 450px and remove horizontal line and place label next to field if it's above 450px. As mentioned above only Safari and Opera desktop browsers would render this properly so I guess if you are testing on local machine use those two browsers.

Thanks everyone who replied!

Comment: Thank you for posting a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view you jsFiddle on a mobile device (I'm using iPhone 4 iOS 5) the styling appears

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that the lines appear on my Android 2.3 device.

Comment: Thanks for testing this guys. Lines are there on my phone too (Windows phone) <-- i know :)

Answer (score 1):

I see what you mean, even on the documentation for jQuery Mobile 1.0 the Field Container section states that there should be a line on the bottom of the container but there isn't (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/docs-forms.html).

If you inspect the CSS rules for the `.ui-field-contain` class you can re-add these styles using CSS:

```
.ui-field-contain {
    border-bottom-width : 1px !important;
    padding-bottom      : 1.5em !important;
}
```

That should do it, the issue is that the jQuery Mobile 1.0 CSS is overwriting the `border-bottom-width` property to `0` for `.ui-field-contain` elements. I also added some padding to give the lines a little space from the inputs.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eQe5A/1/

## UPDATE

After seeing Phill's answer I confirmed that the styling appears when viewing the page on a mobile device (tested with Android 2.3 device).

So the above CSS only changes how the page is rendered in desktop browsers.

Comment: Thanks for reply Jasper. I guess I will leave jQuery Mobile styles as they are since all mobile devices would render those lines.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah the only reason to add the CSS I provided is if you want to force the lines to be present on desktop browsers. I think the reason they don't show-up on desktop browsers is because there is so much more space than in a mobile browser so the lines aren't really necessary.

Comment: You are correct. Take a look at my edit above. I have found few browsers that would render this properly.